# Ajax success is not being called, while request is successfully send

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deepak.php",
        datatype: "html",
        data: 'Name=' + $("#name").val() + '&Email=' + $("#email").val() + '&password=' + $("#password").val() + '&cnfpassword=' + $("#cnfpassword").val(),
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'success') {
            alert("Ajax Successfully Executed")
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

In my php code "success" message is generated via echo function.
ajax works fine , it makes the required request. The only part is not working is the `success`.

here is my server-side code :

```
<?php //Database credentials $dbHost     = 'localhost'; $dbUsername = 'root'; $dbPassword = ''; $dbName     = 'fmc';

//Connect and select the database $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if($db){
    echo 'connected'; } else {
    echo "disconnected"; }


 $name = $_POST['Name'];  $email = $_POST['Email'];  $password = $_POST['password'];  $cnfpassword = $_POST['cnfpassword'];  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO seeifyouqualify (name, email, password, cnfpassword) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password', '$cnfpassword')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);


 if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    echo "success";  } ?>
```

Comment: Include your server side code, as well.

Comment: There's probably something extra around `success`, maybe whitespace. What does `console.log(result)` show?

Comment: place `console.log(result == 'success');` before the `if condition`; to debug it properly, and make sure that you're actually receiving what you're expecting to differentiate in the if condition. - If it's `false` you can always `console.log` the `result`.

I'm quite sure that if the status code received is `2xx`, most probably you're not sending the correct content back.

Comment: add your deepak.php server side code

Comment: Use the network tab in developer tools of your browser to find the response of the ajax request. 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference

Comment: server side code included .

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo`

Comment: You're echoing `connected` aswell as `success`, that's why your JS comparision fails. Also: This is an SQL injection nightmare - use prepared statements.

Comment: I don't use it so can't tell, but you use `datatype: "html"`, are you sure your php return an html datatype?

Comment: my whole page refreshes again when i click on the submit button. So i am not able to ajax response code

Comment: @Screech You need to stop the submit before the ajax call on click on your submit button or change in your html the button type to "button" and no submit?

Comment: great!! Success code : 200 ok

Answer (score 0):

Instead of send all inputs data what you can do is send the form data serialized like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var formData = $("form#yourformId").serialize();
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deepak.php",
        datatype: "html",
        data: {'data_name': formData},
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'success') {
            alert("Ajax Successfully Executed")
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also what I did above is send the data with a name because we have to catch it in `php` like:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['data_name'])){
        //do something....
    }

?>
```

It's important to use `if(isset(...))` because let's say someone went to your `php` page without submitting the form, so `php` wont know what do you mean by `$name = $_POST['name'];`

Now, the last thing is, how to use the serialized data :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['data_name'])){

        $get = explode('&', $_POST['data_name'] ); // explode with and

        foreach ( $get as $key => $value) {
            $valn[ substr( $value, 0 , strpos( $value, '=' ) ) ] =  substr( $value, strpos( 
            $value, '=' ) + 1 ) ;
        }
        // access your query param
        $name = $valn['name'];
        $email = $valn['email'];
        $password = $valn['password'];
        $cnfpassword = $valn['cnfpassword'];

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your javascript if your result is String('success') then only alert will call.
but in your php code you echo output multiple times while connection established and after execute query.So your alert() not working due to ajax response not match your condition.

Comment: I've   already done this by removing the "connected  echo" . But still problem is not resolved.